# Multiple image selecting in android studio

Tags: java, android, cropimage.net

Am trying to select three images and add to the database but the problem comes to selecting all the 3 images. What i know is to select only one image. But in my case i need three selection in my android studio with java. Am using image cropper in my case. The code is shown below with three buttons for images selecting.

I have three Buttons. 1. is for selecting sponsor logo. 2. for team A logo 3. for team B logo

```
sponsorLogo.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            CropImage.activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .start(AddFixtureActivity.this);
        });

        teamALogo.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            CropImage.activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .start(AddFixtureActivity.this);
        });

        teamBLogo.setOnClickListener(v -> {
            CropImage.activity()
                    .setGuidelines(CropImageView.Guidelines.ON)
                    .start(AddFixtureActivity.this);
        });
```

After selecting the images problem comes in forActivityResult. Here i don't know the logic for displaying the images. I want to display them in three places. That is to display them in three different circle image view.
CircleImageView sponsorLogo, teamALogo, teamBLogo;
Let me show you the code for activityResult.

```
 @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE) {
            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                Uri resultUri = result.getUri();
                sponsorLogo.setImageURI(resultUri);
                teamALogo.setImageURI(resultUri);
                teamBLogo.setImageURI(resultUri);
            } else if (resultCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_RESULT_ERROR_CODE) {
                Exception error = result.getError();
            }
        }
    }
```